# How to find the other tables that a foreign key in my table is related to?

Tags: sql-server

database management program: microsoft sql server management studio

I was tasked to study a table,`TableA`, that has a column `empnum`, which serves both as primary key and foreign key. i want to change the contents of `empnum` but seeing as it has the `Enforce Foreign Key Constraint` set to yes, i'm guessing i would have to

1. turn the option off before i can proceed to edit `empnum`
2. find the other table referenced by `empnum` and change that too

My problem is that i do not know how to find the tables (and columns) related to `empnum`.
I would appreciate your help. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show you your table's constraints.

```
sp_helpconstraint('your_table_name')
```